# How to display selection according to the condition ? (element-ui table)

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I have a problem. I want to display selection according to the condition.

Here is the example. I want to hide the selection for the name 'Jeff'

http://jsfiddle.net/8y5cnk1p/2/

If I try to use 'v-if'

```
<el-table-column type="selection" width="45" v-if="name != 'Jeff'" &nbsp;</el-table-column>
```

It doesn't work. How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't *hide* the checkbox, but you can *disable* it using `selectable` attribute:

```html
<el-table-column type="selection"
                 width="45"
                 :selectable="canSelectRow">
</el-table-column>
```

```js
methods: {
  canSelectRow(row, index) {
    return row.name !== 'Jeff';
  }
}
```

Docs: [Table Column Attributes](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#table-column-attributes)

Comment: Nice answer and hide disabled checkbox you can by add display: none for it style: like this .el-table-column--selection {
  .cell {   
    .el-checkbox.is-disabled {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can display the column of checkbox.

```
<el-table-column
  v-if="isShow"
  :key="Math.random()"
  type="selection"
  width="45">
</el-table-column>
```

Don't forget the "key" !!!